# Matlab installation on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: matlab

How to install matlab in ubuntu 12.04 ? which version of matlab is best suited to ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is information about what Matlab versions compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 at the [Platform Road Map for the MATLAB and Simulink Product Families](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/roadmap.html). Look under the heading called *Linux® 64-Bit MATLAB and Simulink Product Families*.

In the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 12.04 there is a package called matlab-support. This package does not provide MATLAB. Instead it configures an existing MATLAB installation to integrate more comfortably in a Debian installation.

There are installation instructions for MATLAB in Ubuntu at the [Ubuntu Documentation MATLAB wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB). Installation instructions for a specific version of MATLAB in Ubuntu can sometimes be found (depending on the version) by searching Ask Ubuntu for that MATLAB version.

Answer (score 0):

run the installer with the -glnx86 argument,

```
sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install -glnx86 -v
```

run MATLAB with the -glnx86 argument to force it to use 32-bit

```
matlab -glnx86
```

**Installation**

1. Run the MATLAB installer(Using following command in terminal).

   `sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install -v`
2. When prompted to 'Choose installation type' you should select custom.
3. When prompted to 'Specify installation folder' it is recommended that you use the default folder `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a`.
4. When given the option to *Create symbolick links to MATLAB scripts in:* it is recommended that you check the box and use the supplied path `/usr/local/bin`.
5. You can check by,

   `sudo matlab`

To know more [click here(source).](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)